# Is it possible to handle reaction events using aiogram?

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

After scanning the web (myself and using ChatGPT), I didn't find a way of handling the emoji reactions users can react with to my bot's messages. I want to create a feedback mechanism for bot behaviour using intuitive reactions such as like & dislike emojis.

Is it achieveable using AIOGram? Does the Telegram API support this in general?

@dp.message_handler() is not called upon a message reaction.
Message().on_reaction or anything like that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

On version `aiogram==3.4.1` you can use `@router.message_reaction()`
[message-reaction documentation](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/router.html#message-reaction)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

Telegram Bot API does not support this.

You have to learn [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/) or [pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/)